# Fix Date Typos in Python

Tags: regex, date, python-3.x

I need to look for dates in OCR'd documents. Using fuzzy regex searches I can find pretty much every date, but the problem is that sometimes the match isn't exactly right and `dateparser.parser` doesn't recognize it. For example, I get matches like `1 1 Jufy 2012` (EN) or `12 juiiiet 20I4` (FR)

I can deal with the numbers, and for my limited knowledge the solution for the month's name would be to create a table of months and fuzzy-regex against it. The problem is that I have to deal with many languages, so it might become lengthy. Is there a quicker way to fix such strings?

Comment: Maybe you could run an automated spell-checker (in the appropriate language) over the text.

Comment: Perhaps this article is of any help: http://www.infogridpacific.com/blog/igp-blog-20130317-ocr-production-nightmares.html

Comment: @tobias_k Interesting idea, although it might be an overkill to simply match the 12 month's names

Comment: @Mariano Nice article. In summary I guess it's your long winded way of saying "get better images"?

Comment: @chris: haha, in a way... Also, there's a list of common defects that you can use to predict what a month could be recognized as